# Inverse limits over coinitial sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

Given a directed set $A$, a subset $B \subset A$ is said to be *coinitial* if for every $a \in A$ there is some $b \in B$ such that $b \leq a$.

Now consider an inverse system of rings $(S_i, f_{ij})$ indexed by $A$ and let $B \subset A$ be coinitial.

> Is it true that $\varprojlim_{i \in A}S_i \cong \varprojlim_{i \in B} S_i$?

I am aware that the answer is true if $B$ is cofinal instead of coinitial. I as wondering if there is some sort of modification in the proof for cofinal sets that works as well for coinitial sets. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To get an inverse system, shouldn't you ask for a *codirected* set $A$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Pardon my ignorance, but I don't know what a codirected set is...

Comment: If the homomorphisms in your inverse system go from $S_i$ to $S_j$ with $i\geq j$, then you want a directed index set $A$, and the inverse limit will be unchanged (up to isomorphism) if you replace $A$ with a cofinal subset $B$. If, on the other hand, the homomorphisms in your inverse system go from $S_i$ to $S_j$ with $i\leq j$, then you want a co-directed index set $A$ (i.e., every two elements have a common lower bound), and the inverse limit will be unchanged (up to isomorphism) if you replace $A$ with a coinitial subset $B$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you your comment. It seems more clear now. Can you point me to any reference (book or notes) where I can find the result you quote?

Comment: @user313212 I'm confused : you say in your question that you know already know the result for $B$ cofinal. I guess this is in the first case mentioned by Andreas? Note that the second is really the same result, but with the order relation inverted.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Okay, it's just that I am not too familiar with those concepts as you can tell, but I believe it is clearer now. I was just asking for some references in the matter so I can understand this sort of things better.